# Access Webcam in Jupyter Notebook on Xilinx Pynq FPGA

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, webcam, fpga

Hey guys I want to get the live video frames from my usb webcam connected to my Pynq FPGA. The goal is to make motion detection on each frame but I've been struggling to get a live video. I've tried the first example in this [link](https://medium.com/@neotheicebird/webcam-based-image-processing-in-ipython-notebooks-47c75a022514) but I get a really bad frame rate. I tried to get a better rate by adding the following line:`vc.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60)` but it didn't change anything. I tried an example in MATLAB and I had no problems connecting to the webcam and I had a smooth frame rate.

I've read that OpenCV can't be used together with Python3 yet but I still get images in the notebook what I don't understand. I also don't know how to install other packages or libraries like pygame for jupyter notebooks on the pynq, it says everywhere that I have to enter pip install "name" and put the library in the site-packages directory but I haven't seen that directory on jupyter notebooks. So I'm trying to find a way without installing new libraries.

I really need your help guys, do you have some suggestions how to get a live video stream from my webcam on jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV can work with python3. I am using that
at first you need to install pip, it is pretty easy flow.
After that connect the board to the web and use pip install